# Dash app - is it possible to import/export all of a user's current selections to a file?

Tags: python, import, save, export, plotly-dash

Currently have a web application built on Plotly-Dash. I’ve been looking for some way to allow the users to save all of their different selections into some sort of file that they can import back into the Dash app in the future in case they want to replicate exactly what they had up previously.

My app is essentially an interactive dashboard with a lot of different options meaning remembering/documenting every selection that led to a specific result would be quite tiresome… having some sort of way to save the entire current state of the web app for easy access/import later would be huge. This would also allow users to share their specific results with other users quite easily.

I’ve been doing a lot of research and I can’t find something that does this for me in Dash, but the usefulness of such a feature seems great enough that I would be surprised if it didn’t exist. Can someone point me in the right direction? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that we can simply dump/load the children of app.layout object using pickle module, like

```py
app.layout = html.Div(children=[...],
        id= "layout"
    )

@app.callback(
    output = Output("save_button", "n_clicks"),
    inputs = dict(
                n_clicks=Input("save_button", "n_clicks"),
                item=State("layout", "children"),
            ),
    prevent_initial_call=True
)
def save(n_clicks, item):
    if n_clicks is not None and n_clicks>0:
        pickle.dump(item, open("path_to_the_file", "wb"))
    return n_clicks
```

load can be done in a similar way.